# How to optimise and speed up .find and .build on large number of records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rails-activerecord, select-n-plus-1

I have a form that accepts a true/false value for every hour of the day for 3 weeks (total of 504 1 hour time slots).

I am trying to reduce the time it takes for this page to load (currently 3 seconds locally, but 15 seconds on heroku; more than twice the time of any other page on the site).

#### The code

The form looks like this:

```
<% 504.times do |i| %>
    
  <% availability = @physician.availabilities.find { |a| a.time_slot == @current_hour + (i + 1)*3600 } %>
  <% availability ||= @physician.availabilities.build(time_slot: all_one_hour_slots[i] ) %>

# Form etc
```

Small numbers of `i` would be fine, but because it happens 504 times, it's slow.

When I view the server logs, it has the appearance of an n+1 problem (which I think may be caused by `@physician.availabilities.find`). But I'm not sure if that can be successfully avoided whilst maintaining functionality.

#### Question

How can I retain functionality, but make the page load faster?

#### Other notes

- Every page on the site loads in under 7 seconds, so this page being 15 seconds is quite problematic.
- The heroku dyno is [standard](https://www.heroku.com/pricing), and the heroku postgres database is [hobby-basic](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql).
- I am open to using whatever approach is best to reduce time. For example, if code optimisation is possible, that would be great. But if increasing the postgres database from hobby-basic to standard-0 would help, I'd consider that too.
- A sample of the logs (this is 6 lines almost identical, but there are 504 total like this!):

```
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT "appointments"."start_time" FROM "appointments" WHERE "appointments"."physician_id" = $1  [["physician_id", 10]]
  ↳ app/views/physicians/_form.html.erb:37
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT "appointments"."start_time" FROM "appointments" WHERE "appointments"."physician_id" = $1  [["physician_id", 10]]
  ↳ app/views/physicians/_form.html.erb:37
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT "appointments"."start_time" FROM "appointments" WHERE "appointments"."physician_id" = $1  [["physician_id", 10]]
  ↳ app/views/physicians/_form.html.erb:37
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT "appointments"."start_time" FROM "appointments" WHERE "appointments"."physician_id" = $1  [["physician_id", 10]]
  ↳ app/views/physicians/_form.html.erb:37
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT "appointments"."start_time" FROM "appointments" WHERE "appointments"."physician_id" = $1  [["physician_id", 10]]
  ↳ app/views/physicians/_form.html.erb:37
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT "appointments"."start_time" FROM "appointments" WHERE "appointments"."physician_id" = $1  [["physician_id", 10]]
  ↳ app/views/physicians/_form.html.erb:37
```

#### Longer explanation

Here's the form in the view

```
<% 504.times do |i| %>

  <% availability = @physician.availabilities.find { |a| a.time_slot == @current_hour + (i + 1)*3600 } %>
  <% availability ||= @physician.availabilities.build(time_slot: all_one_hour_slots_from_one_hour_after_current_time[i] ) %>


  <% if @appointments.pluck(:start_time).any? { |e| e == availability.time_slot } %> 
    <b><%= availability.time_slot.to_s + " Time slot booked" %></b>
  <% else %><%# Line 37 %>
    <%= form.fields_for :availabilities, availability do |availability_form| %>

      <%= availability_form.hidden_field :time_slot, value: availability.time_slot %>

      <%= availability_form.label :_destroy do %>
        <%= availability_form.check_box :_destroy, {checked: availability.persisted?}, '0', '1' %>
        <%= nice_datetime(availability.time_slot) %>
      <% end %>

    <% end %><%# end form.fields_for %>
  <% end %><%# end booked vs available %>

<% end %><%# end 504 loop %>
```

And here's the controller action

```
# physicians controller
@physician = current_user.physician
@appointments = Physician.find(current_user.physician.id).appointments
@current_hour = Time.current.beginning_of_hour
```

A quick explanation in words: basically the 504 loop is just looping through 504 1 hour time slots and either displaying " Time slot booked" if that time is already booked, or a checkbox if the time slot is not booked (so the physician can decide whether to make themselves available for that time slot).

Lastly, full logs [here](https://pastebin.com/FGgEcQjc)

Comment: You should start by querying for just the availablities you want in the controller. `@availabilities = @physician.availabilities.where(time_slot: @current_hour..@current_hour.advance(weeks: 3))`. And then iterating across the collection in the view. Its not actually clear here what the functionality you're attempting to maintain is but DB queries in the view are a strong code smell - as is using find with a block.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure here but when you call `.find` with a block it will load the entire assocation with a database query and convert it into an array. You're then using `Enumberable#find` to just take the first element that matches your condition and then tossing the rest. Its like buying en entire pizza to just get an olive. Do that 504 times and its gonna be real slow.

Comment: @max thanks very much Max. It sounds like I should try to query once for the availabilities and essentially do what those two lines are doing  in the controller and pass the resulting array to the view if possible

Comment: Yes. If you need more detailed advice we need a better picture of the models and the feature.

Comment: Hi @max Thanks for your help. I have included a section at the bottom of the question with a brief explanation of what's going on (it's actually simple to describe in words), as well as the code from the form and the controller (there's obviously a 'submit' button which I've omitted for brevity)